# VSCode extension debugging dont use the latest updated code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I try to edit a vscode extension, update and add some customization, but when I debug it by pressing `F5`, my changes seem like not being executed. Even when I try to remove a piece of code that I am sure will break the extension, but unfotunately it still run like there are no changes at all. Am I wrong debugging it or there's caches that we should remove?

Btw I am using VSCode 1.52.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

My `launch.json`:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"]
    }]
}
```

Comment: add a call to show an information message or just `console.log('Hello')`, set breakpoints and see if the debugger stops

Comment: breakpoints work but `console.log` doesn't

Comment: do you have the same problems if you use the hello world example (Typescript and/or Javascript version)

Comment: Most projects require ˋnpm run compileˋ to be executed before debugging. Check the notes left by the project owners or read ˋprojects.json`

Comment: Yeah, my bad @rioV8, Lex Li is right that I need to recompile and restart it. It works now. Thank you both

Comment: to always recompile before debug, add `preLaunchTask` to the `launch.json` config.

Comment: facing the same problem with the python project.